# Line of sight NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

How do I implement a line of sight in NetLogo whereby

> A turtle calculates/counts all turtles between it and the a given patch on the line of sight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that each turtle has a  `turtles-own` called target, which is the given patch, you can ask each turtle to face the target patch and count all the turtles between it and the given patch:

```
ask turtles [
  face target
  let n 1
  let c 0
  while [patch-ahead (n - 1) != target][  
    ask patch-ahead n [
       if any? turtles-here [set c (c + 1)]
    ]
    set n (n + 1)
  ]
  print (word who " has " c " turtles on the line of sight")
]
```

A while loop doesn't look very clean in NetLogo but it works.

Comment: This is not correct. If you try `ca crt 1 [ setxy -0.5 -0.5 set target patch 1 1 ]` and then run your code, it will say that there is 1 turtle on the line of sight. The diagonal of a patch is √2, so stepping by 1 can count the same patch twice. (It can also miss the corners of some patches.)

Answer (score 1):

See Line of Sight Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Dr_stein

```
To-report count-turtles-on-line-to[target]
 Let c 0
 Let d distance target
 Face target
 While d > 0
    [
    Let c c + count turtles-on patch-ahead d
    Let d d - 1
    ]
 Report c
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `patches-ahead` reporter from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26800746/487946):

```
to-report patches-ahead [ dist step ]
  report patch-set map patch-ahead n-values (dist / step) [ step + ? * step ]
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  ask turtles [
    let target one-of patches
    face target
    show (word
      count other turtles-on patches-ahead distance target 0.1
      " turtles between me and " target)
  ]
end
```